# I need to wait untill i didnt get response and all data in android fb sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I want to wait until `onCompleted()` of my callback function of a Request is not finished.

i have written below code:

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                // Application code
                                Log.v("LoginActivity",
                                        response.toString());
                                try {

                                    username = object
                                            .getString("first_name");

                                    emailid = object.getString("email");


                                    gender = object.getString("gender");

                                    bday = object.getString("birthday");

                                    //new User().execute(emailid);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch
                                    // block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields",
                        "id,first_name,email,gender, birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            }
        });
```

i need to wait until my request is not completed. and after getting all data like email , gender etc  i want to execute my function `new User().execute(emailid);`

How can i wait until i didnt get all the data from response.?

Answer (score 0):

-----FOLLOWING ANSWERS: **How can I wait until the request IS completed to run my code?**

put your code like this:

```
    @Override
public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
      try {
        ... //put your code here, will only run if response is ok
      } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
      }
    }[...]
```

you WILL have the data once the

`@Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {[...]`

has run because onSuccess has already run meaning the response was successful.

Comment: i need to wait untill i didnt get all the data like email , bday , gender etc.

Comment: sorry for my bad question. please check the update quesiton.

Comment: you are still saying "not finished" this means you need to run your code BEFORE the request is completed? @deepak

Comment: No i dont want to run my code before the request is not completed and i didnt get data.
I want to run my code after getting response and data .

Comment: i need to wait untill i didnt get data like email , birthday , gender etc. 
When i will get all this data then and then only i want to run my funciton until i want to wait for that.

Comment: and `response==200` will not work because it Incompatible operand types GraphResponse and int.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84490/discussion-between-stephen-miller-and-deepak).

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any response , if you make `GraphRequest` within `onCompleted()` function. So avoid making `GraphRequest` within `onCompleted()` function. `GraphRequest` must call from UI thread. So just make `GraphRequest` from any UI thread functions. Surely you will get response.

Comment: I didnt get.!!. I have to call  `GraphRequest request` from other `AsyncTask` method on the UI?